# Internationalising WPF Input in Convertor

Tags: c#, wpf, internationalization

I am writing a converter for my WPF application that will require the presentation of a variable number of decimal places for a column. The number of decimal places can be altered for a column by the user using a key combination or a form button. The only difference is that if the precision is increased and the final digit is a 0, then the precision will not increase.

Hence for a column with a precision of 3 decimal places, the following values 123.123 and 123.100 would be displayed as 123.123 and 123.1.

This is working fine for me at the moment. The problem arises when I try and internationalise this. I have read various threads and pages in regards to Internationalisation however still seem unable to get this working correctly. I'd appreciate it if somebody could take a look and point out any obvious problems that I may have overlooked.

The behaviour that is being observed is as follows. When displaying data, the convertor seems to be working fine and formatting numbers correctly according to the users regional settings. When a user updates data then German users are experiencing the following behaviour.

Enter     Displayed            Expected Display
1000      1.000                 1.000
1.000     1         1.000
1,000     1.000                 1
1,234     1.234                 1,234

My convertor code is as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace xxx
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
    public class StripDecimalsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly Regex NumberRegex = new Regex("(?<=[A-Z])(\\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //return any integer values to 0 dp. Else apply the default decimal places to the value.
            string convertedformat = parameter.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("P") ? "{0:P0}" : "{0:N0}";

            string format = parameter.ToString();

            int converted;

            var convertedCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

            if (value == null) return string.Format(culture, format, string.Empty);
            else if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out converted))
                return string.Format(convertedCulture, convertedformat, converted);
            else
            {

                Double d;
                Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d);
                var x = (double)value;
                var strippedFormat = StrippedFormat(x, format, convertedCulture);

                return string.Format(convertedCulture, strippedFormat, x);
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }



        private string StrippedFormat(double value, string format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            var scaleMatch = NumberRegex.Match(format);
            //What format value is being sent in by the formatter?
            int requiredprecision = scaleMatch != Match.Empty ? Int32.Parse(scaleMatch.Value) : 0;

            Double d = value;

            int index = d.ToString().IndexOf(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
            //How many decimakl places are in the value to be formatted?
            var formatlength = d.ToString().Substring(index + 1).Length;
            string newformat = requiredprecision > formatlength
                            ? (format.Contains("P") ? string.Format("{{0:P{0}}}", formatlength) : string.Format("{{0:N{0}}}", formatlength))
                            : (format.Contains("P")
                                   ? string.Format("{{0:P{0}}}", requiredprecision)
                                   : string.Format("{{0:N{0}}}", requiredprecision));

            return newformat;
        }
    }
}
```

The convertor is called from my XAML as follows:

```
StringFormat={}{0:N2},Converter={StaticResource StripDecimalsConverter},ConverterParameter=\{0:N2\}}"
```

My App.xaml also contains the line:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

Any pointers in the right direction will be most appreciated.